# How to get the last 7 weeks, 7 months date range from current date PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, datetime

How can I get the date range of last seven weeks /months from the current date, i have already done with last seven days

**fetch last seven days, weeks and month sales total grouped by 7 particular days, 7 particular weeks and 7 particular months**

ex:

```
Today : 08/18/2021
```

Last seven weeks

```
08/08/2021 - 08/14/2021
08/01/2021 - 08/07/2021
etc.
```

Last seven Months

```
07/01/2021 - 07/31/2021
06/01/2021 - 06/30/2021
etc.
```

The below query I have done for last seven days

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$lastsevenDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
SELECT
    sales.salesDay as sales_day,
    ROUND(sum( IFNULL( payment.tmpNetTotal, 0 ) ),2)AS sales,
    payment.createdDateTime as Day_date
    FROM
    srp_erp_pos_menusalesmaster AS sales
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM( IFNULL( amount, 0 ) ) AS tmpNetTotal,createdDateTime, menuSalesID FROM srp_erp_pos_menusalespayments WHERE createdDateTime BETWEEN '" . $lastsevenDays . "' AND '" . $today . "'  GROUP BY menuSalesID ) AS payment ON sales.menuSalesID = payment.menuSalesID 
                WHERE isHold = 0 AND sales.isVoid = 0 AND companyID = $companyID GROUP BY
                sales.salesDay ORDER BY
                payment.createdDateTime
```

Now as the same way, I am thinking a way to fetch last 7 weeks and last seven months.

Comment: And what is the problem you're unable to solve?

Comment: I wanna get the last seven weeks and month sales, I wanna query looping through a date range

Comment: Is this database querying? You said nothing about a database in your question. My point was that you cannot just say "I want", or in other words; "Make this for me", you have to show some effort yourself, tell us what the problem is you encountered, what you tried to solve it and why you failed. Then we can help you.

Comment: I have modified the question, I have already done for  last seven days, But i couldn't figure out how to do for last 7 weeks and months, I passing date range in query

Comment: Could you show your code for getting the last 7 days?

Comment: So then please a) show your code doing it for last 7 days, and then b) show how you attempted to modify it for the new requirements, and explain what went wrong when you tried to run it. Then we'll know you've actually made a reasonable attempt at this.

Comment: I have added the code @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Thanks. So, `strtotime('-49 days')` will not work for 7 weeks?

Comment: Thank you by the way, it should fetch like week by week totals, not the whole total at once.

Comment: It's probably better to use native MySQL function for this. Something like `WHERE createdDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK)`. I left out the current data in the assumption you won't be creating stuff now but say you created it in the future. Grouping by week is somewhat more difficult. That requires a real answer, but the grouping by weeks, or months, is not part of your question. Comments are not part of the question, someone wanting to answer your question shouldn't have to pick up clues from the comments.

Comment: The above native function will result only one result, it will not group by days to my knowledge

Comment: I know. However, you first said it should fetch week by week totals, and now you say it should group by days. Which is it?

Comment: ok let me clear for you, All what I have to do is, Wanna fetch last seven days, weeks and month sales total grouped by 7 particular days, 7 particular weeks and particular months

Comment: Ah, that's clear.

Comment: @Khn you are far more likely to receive complete, tested, proven answers if you provide a db fiddle link with enough sample data.  This is why a [mcve] is so vital to good pages on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, But I couldn't its a heavy DB.

Comment: That's why Stack Overflow specifically calls it a "minimal" reproducible example.  We need the schema with _just enough rows_ to create a verifiable result -- enough data to generate identifiable differences/accuracy in the 3 groups. @Khn

Comment: You want the result in three rows or three columns?

Comment: @SalmanA columns

Comment: Please edit the question and post the expected result. Also explain the edge cases with dates e.g. if input date is `Wed Aug/18/2021` then does past 7 week start from `Thu Jul/01/2021` and past 7 month start from `Feb/19/2021` or some other dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have each single "day" summarized in a single table, then it is easy to summarize that over the last N days, whether there is several weeks or months.

If the summary table has `sum_dollars`, `count_items`, then

```
SELECT
    SUM(sum_dollars) -- total dollars over the larger period
    SUM(count_items) -- how many items there were
    SUM(sum_dollars) / SUM(count_items) -- average price
    FROM summary_table
    WHERE date ...
```

(Note that I did not have `avg_price` in the summary table because `AVG(avg_..)` is usually the wrong formula.)

So, build and maintain (nightly) a summary table by day.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

PS.  "today" is `CURDATE()` in SQL.  More specifically, that is midnight this morning.  "7 months ago" is `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH`

Likely BUG:  Don't use `BETWEEN`; it is 'inclusive'.  Instead, do something like

```
WHERE createdDateTime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH
  AND createdDateTime  < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to cobble together a query that sort of does what you want for the weeks, I hope. First the whole query:

```
SELECT
  S.salesDay as sales_day,
  ROUND(sum(IFNULL(P.tmpNetTotal, 0)),2) AS sales,
  P.createdDateTime as Day_date
FROM 
  srp_erp_pos_menusalesmaster AS S
JOIN (SELECT 
        SUM(IFNULL(amount, 0)) AS tmpNetTotal,
        createdDateTime, 
        menuSalesID 
      FROM 
        srp_erp_pos_menusalespayments 
      WHERE 
        createdDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK)
      GROUP BY 
        menuSalesID) AS P ON S.menuSalesID = P.menuSalesID 
WHERE 
  S.isHold = 0 AND 
  S.isVoid = 0 AND 
  S.companyID = $companyID 
GROUP BY 
   FLOOR((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(DATE(S.salesDay))) / 7)    
ORDER BY 
  P.createdDateTime
```

**My assumption is that `sales.salesDay` contains a proper date and time.**

I changed two things:

- In the inner `SELECT` I changed the condition to `WHERE createdDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK)`, using functions in MySQL instead of in PHP.
- To group by weeks I changed the grouping to: `GROUP BY FLOOR((TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(DATE(S.salesDay))) / 7)`, using the [FLOOR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) function. I convert date/time to dates and then to a day number. subtracting those give you the days in the past, divide by 7 and taking the `FLOOR()` gives you weeks.

The same can be done for months.

**Code is untested and might not work perfectly, but I hope this gives you a way forward.**

Comment: Noticed an error, and corrected it. The subtraction in the `GROUP BY` should be between brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, by the way this isn't working as expected, this gives only one result and not grouped by days

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try This:

```
$today           = date("Y-m-d");
$lastsevenDays   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
$lastsevenMonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 months'));

// Last seven weeks
SELECT
    sales.salesDay as sales_day,
    ROUND(sum( IFNULL( payment.tmpNetTotal, 0 ) ),2)AS sales,
    payment.createdDateTime as Day_date
    FROM
    srp_erp_pos_menusalesmaster AS sales
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM( IFNULL( amount, 0 ) ) AS tmpNetTotal,createdDateTime, menuSalesID FROM srp_erp_pos_menusalespayments WHERE DATE(createdDateTime) >= DATE($lastsevenDays) AND DATE(createdDateTime) < DATE($today)  GROUP BY menuSalesID ) AS payment ON sales.menuSalesID = payment.menuSalesID 
                WHERE isHold = 0 AND sales.isVoid = 0 AND companyID = $companyID GROUP BY
                sales.salesDay ORDER BY
                payment.createdDateTime;

// Last seven Months

SELECT
    sales.salesDay as sales_day,
    ROUND(sum( IFNULL( payment.tmpNetTotal, 0 ) ),2)AS sales,
    payment.createdDateTime as Day_date
    FROM
    srp_erp_pos_menusalesmaster AS sales
    JOIN ( SELECT SUM( IFNULL( amount, 0 ) ) AS tmpNetTotal,createdDateTime, menuSalesID FROM srp_erp_pos_menusalespayments WHERE DATE(createdDateTime) >= DATE($lastsevenMonths) AND DATE(createdDateTime) < DATE($today)  GROUP BY menuSalesID ) AS payment ON sales.menuSalesID = payment.menuSalesID 
                WHERE isHold = 0 AND sales.isVoid = 0 AND companyID = $companyID GROUP BY
                sales.salesDay ORDER BY
                payment.createdDateTime;
```